# CKEditor: Tabletools doesnt remember my properties

Tags: dialog, ckeditor, tabletools

ive installed CKEditor on my website with the tabletools Plugins from here: http://ckeditor.com/addon/tabletools. Everything but the tabletool dialog works well.

For example: I have edited my table cell width to 33.333% and hit ok. A few minutes later I wanted to set a background color on that table cell, but unfortunatly the width (and all the other changes ive made in that dialog) was empty. That means that i cant make any further changes to that cell if i dont want to fill all the other again. Does anyone knows if this is intended and if their are any solutions to get the fields filled again?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty certain that next time you (unconsciously) select different table cells than previously. Unfortunately it's not visible, because browsers render selections in tables poorly. For example selection may be extended to contain beginning of next cell and in such case you will see only selection in the first cell.

To make sure that on right click selection won't overflow current cell make sure to click in the middle of the text. Or, if you mistakenly opened dialog for two table cells (then width of first cell won't be loaded into the dialog), just set the values you want to change and editor won't reset those values which you haven't filled.